# Azure DevOps pipeline missing ComponentSpace licence

Tags: .net-core, build, azure-devops, pipeline, component-space

When trying to run pipeline build on Azure DevOps,I'm receiving following error:

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1101: Unable to find package ComponentSpace.Saml2.Licensed. No packages exist with this id in source(s): NuGetOrg
```

Can someone point me to the article of how to include the licence? or can tell me how to fix it to pass the build?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

NuGet Error NU1101 means the package cannot be found on any sources.

> **Solution**
>
> Examine the project's dependencies in Visual Studio to be sure you're
> using the correct package identifier and version number. Also check
> that the NuGet configuration identifies the package sources you are
> expected to be using. If you use packages that have Semantic
> Versioning 2.0.0, please make sure that you are using the V3 feed,
> `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`, in the NuGet configuration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1101

Answer (score 0):

For my builds in Azure what I had to do was remove the Component Space reference in my web app packages.config after installing. In this way the dll is still referenced and pushed into source control but the Azure step to restore packages doesn't fail as it doesn't know about the custom package.